# Running jzy3d demos result in ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, jzy3d

The problem is as follows, during startup of the jzy3d demo ScatterDemo.java :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GLProfile
at org.jzy3d.chart.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:19)
at org.jzy3d.chart.Settings.getInstance(Settings.java:48)
at org.jzy3d.analysis.AnalysisLauncher.open(AnalysisLauncher.java:18)
at org.jzy3d.analysis.AnalysisLauncher.open(AnalysisLauncher.java:13)
at org.jzy3d.demos.scatter.ScatterDemo.main(ScatterDemo.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.opengl.GLProfile
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 5 more
Java Result: 1
```

Configuration is NetBeans 7.3.1, jzy3d-api-0.9.1, jzy3d-swt-0.9.1, log4j-1.2.17, gluegen-rt (latest stable), jogl-all (latest stable), JDK1.7

I am aware of the following change (Moving all of javax.media.opengl to com.jogamp.opengl, https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=682). I have gone through the usual process of including .jar files into the project.

Project compiles fine, does not run.

My question(s) are: Can I somehow redirect javax.media.opengl.* to com.jogamp.opengl.* ? What is the correct way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/blob/master/jzy3d-api/src/api/org/jzy3d/plot3d/rendering/canvas/VoidCanvas.java#L6), even the code on the master branch (0.9.2) isn't based on the latest version of JOGL. Please ask Martin Pernollet to make the necessary changes (replace javax.media.* by com.jogamp.*) or do it yourself. You can rebuild Jzy3d to test it with the modifications of the import clauses. This is the correct way of solving this simple problem.

Comment: I have sent a message to Martin regarding this issue and will rebuild the source myself. Thank you.